# How to fold terabyte of words with Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Will Hadoop help to solve the following problem:

I need to fold 1000GB of words into a single word according to some rules. For example:

```
 fold("dog","cat") = "pet"
```

In what order words are folded is not important. I was thinking to split all data into several chunks and fold words inside every chunk first. After that fold resulting words.

Questions:

1) Does it make sense to use Hadoop for this task?

2) How many chunks to create and what size chunk should be for Hadoop to work efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like hadoop would help in the sense that this seems like a batch operation across a large amount of data, but what does fold() do exactly? do you have it defined? do you have a file/list that says "dog" --> "pet", "cat" --> "pet", "snake" --> "wild"?

Comment: I have '+' operation defined on set of chars. So for example 'd' + 'c' = 'p' , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem now.  For the sake of simplicity, consider an example where we will simply be adding 1000GB worth of integers (as you said addition can roughly equate to your fold() operation).

So Map/Reduce has two phases - Map phase operates on a single data item (key, value pair), then feeds to a Reduce phase where aggregation can occur.  Since your whole operation is one huge aggregation, you can use Hadoop's identity [Mapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) along with a [Combiner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setCombinerClass%28java.lang.Class%29) to break up the aggregation into a few, smaller ones.

A Combiner is basically a Reducer that runs right after the Mapper of your job.  The idea of it is to do aggregations on the data exiting a Map node to combine whatever it can and reduce the amount of data sent over the network to the Reduce nodes.

Here's an example of an addition combiner

```
  public class AddCombiner extends Reducer<SomeKey, IntWritable, SomeKey, IntWritable> {
     public void reduce(SomeKey key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
     {
       int total = 0;

       for (IntWritable value : values) 
       {
           total += value.get();
       }

       context.write(key, new IntWritable(total));
     }
   }
```

So you can run a Map/Reduce job on your 1000GB of input, have Combiners do the first level of aggregations after the Map tasks and then have one Reducer which takes the aggregated data from the Combiners and does one final aggregation into your final answer.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Still question remains: How to split 1000GB of words across HDFS to reduce number of computations and transfers between nodes? Should it be one file or many small files?

Comment: Where are you getting from the data from? Is it already in files somewhere?

Comment: So far I have just 4 huge files. Don't know how to put them in Hadoop.

Comment: putting them in HDFS is just a matter of doing 'hadoop fs -put'. As far as optimal way to split them, I'm not sure. It will likely be a trial & measure thing.  For starters though, you can just add those 4 files to HDFS as I said above.  There are also configurations, such as mapred.max.split.size, that can be used to create more/less splits